# rosbag service?

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a topic, actionlib, or service interface for controlling the recording of bag files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40897/rosbag-service?/) by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3838 on 2012-08-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Related really old post: http://lists.ros.org/lurker/message/20100624.102701.faa666b4.en.html (was http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/rosbag-external-control-td920048.html)

> I was wondering if there is a way to
> make rosbag expose a service to
> pause/resume the recording? This would
> be quite useful in a data-collection
> application we are currently building,
> where we don't need to record all the
> time, but only on certain segments of
> the trajectory.
>
> Any thought on this functionality?
>
> Thanks
>
> Dr. Cedric Pradalier
> http://www.asl.ethz.ch/people/cedricp

---

> Hi Cedric,
>
> Yes, that functionality is on our
> roadmap. Until then, you could look to
> rosbag/recorder.cpp and
> rxbag/recorder.py for implementations
> of bag recorders. It should be
> straightforward to add service-based
> pausing/resuming on top of those.
>
> Fyi, notes on planned future ROS
> functionality are kept here:
> http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Roadmap.
> It's great to get feedback from the
> community about what features would be
> useful, though.
>
> Thanks, Tim

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0